# Problem looping through marker.layers and changing only one CCS layer properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet, marker

I have several markers on a map. They load and add and remove well but I cant change one CSS element on just one marker, I can find the layerm. If I loop through the layers but find the correct one and apply the change it changes all the marker layers CSS properties? I will show a basic run down of it.

How I add markers :-

```
    var client = L.divIcon({
    className: 'location-pin',          
    html: '<img id"operatorimg" src="img/'+point.name+'.jpg"><div id="pin" class="pin busy"></div>',
    iconSize: [60, 60],
    iconAnchor: [20, 66]});
    
    var marker = L.marker ([point.lat, point.lng], {
        icon: client
    });
    
    markerLayer.addLayer(marker);

    marker.name = point.name;
    status = point.status;  
    var username = point.name;      
    marker.bindPopup(username + ' is online but is busy');
```

Data loaded like so :-

```
const pointsForMarker = [
  { name: 'LILLY', lat: 52.4904975, lng: -1.5151260, ID: 100101, status: 'ONLINE'},
  { name: 'SAM', lat: 52.4734975, lng: -1.4911260, ID: 100102, status: 'OFFLINE'}
];
```

I loop through and add the markers like so :-

```
pointsForMarker.forEach((point) => {

if (point.status === 'ONLINE') {

    var client = L.divIcon({
        className: 'location-pin',          
        html: '<img id"operatorimg" src="img/'+point.name+'.jpg"><div id="pin" class="pin online"></div><div class="pulse"></div>',
        iconSize: [60, 60],
        iconAnchor: [20, 66]});

        
        var marker = L.marker ([point.lat, point.lng], {
            icon: client
        });
        
        markerLayer.addLayer(marker);
        marker.name = point.name;
        status = point.status;
        var username = point.name;      
        marker.bindPopup(username + ' is online now and available');
```

Now i can remove the marker like so and it works :-

```
markerLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
    var markerToDismiss = "LILLY";
    if (markerToDismiss) {

      if (layer.name.trim().toLowerCase() === markerToDismiss.trim().toLowerCase()
      ) {
        layer.removeFrom(markerLayer);
      }
```

But if i try the same and change the CSS is changes all the markers CSS when I only want it to change the matching one like the delete does???

I am trying :-

```
//// test delete marker ///
markerLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
    var markerTochange = "LILLY";

alert(layer.name);

      if (layer.name === markerTochange)
       {
        //layer.removeFrom(markerLayer);
        layer.name = $(".pin").css("background", "red");
      }
 
  }
```

The CSS for the style is :-

```
.location-pin img {
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  margin: -53px 0 0 -26px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #32383e;
}

.pin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -86px 0 0 -60px;
}

.user-location-pin img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: -26px 0 0 -13px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #32383e;
}

.user-pin {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -43px 0 0 -30px;
}


.pulse {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}


.online {
      background: green;
}
.offline {
      background: red;
}

.busy {
      background: orange;
}


.location-user img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -43px 0 0 -30px;
}

.user-pin {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #32383e;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -43px 0 0 -30px;
}

.pulse {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 2.5s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(94,190,255,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #2d99d3;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I really wish I could show example but am new to all of this and dont know how to and sorry if I am not doing this correctly. I will look at that jfiddle to see if I can add it.

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to do it! I added the user name to the DIV ID and the status to the class. I can control the individual markers quite easily by looping through the users and getting the names.

I add the name to the DIV and assign the class to status, which in return changes the color of the marker with the following :-

```
    var status;
    var username;
    usersOnlineStatus.forEach((point) => {
    
    // status = status.point.trim().toLowerCase();
    
    
    username = point.name;
    status = point.status;
    
    
        var client = L.divIcon({
            className: 'location-pin',          
            html: '<img id="operatorimg" src="img/'+point.name+'.jpg"><div id='+username+' class="pin '+status+'"></div>',
            iconSize: [60, 60],
            iconAnchor: [20, 66]});

And to find the marker and change the DIV, I look like so :-

usersOnlineStatus.forEach((point) => {

    var status = point.status;
    var mname = point.name;
    
    var nametoupdate = mname; 
    
    if (status ==="online") {
    
    var nametoupdate = '#' + nametoupdate;
    $(nametoupdate).removeClass("online");
    $(nametoupdate).removeClass("offline");
    $(nametoupdate).removeClass("busy");
    $(nametoupdate).addClass("online");
    }
}
```

I have a problem deleting the marker from the cluster but I am trying!